# 9.999501.toFixed(3) = '10.000' but 9.9995000000000001.toFixed(3) = '9.999'

Tags: javascript

```
> 9.9995.toFixed(3)
'9.999'
> 9.999501.toFixed(3)
'10.000'
> 9.9995000001.toFixed(3)
'10.000'
> 9.9995000000001.toFixed(3)
'10.000'
> 9.9995000000000001.toFixed(3)
'9.999'
```

I've been writing a simple function to render a percentage into 6 string characters for generating aligned output. Once I did some testing focused on rounding I ran into this weird rounding behavior. Anyone know what's going on?

It seems likely that 9.9995000000000001 is too many digits and evaluates identically to 9.9995, but it still begs the question of why the rounding threshold is not met by 9.9995

Comment: Because there is no floating-point binary number with the exact value of 9.9995

Comment: The floating point representation of your number must be slightly less than 9.9995.

Comment: yeah i think i can chalk this up to binary representation of 9.9995 *actually* being 9.999499 or whatever, which wouldn't actually round up so it's still possible for the rounding up behavior not to be at fault here. So it is the same floating point dragons I was supposed to be familiar with.

Comment: Try `.toPrecision(18)` instead of `.toFixed(3)` and yo will see, how the number is scanned and converted into an internal number. So `toFixed(3)` works absolutely perfect for your examples.